# Free (if possible) Video Converter

Tags: macos, video, encoding

I've been getting along with VisualHub (defunct) for a while now, but recently I've needed an expanded set of Codec's, in particular Theora and VP8.<sup>[1](http://diveintohtml5.com/video.html)</sup>

Comment: for encoding or decoding or both?

Comment: @calavera: Both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) might be what you're looking for. It is free and supports Theora and VP8.

Comment: Can you get FFmpeg to build natively on 10.6.2? Mine hangs on configure.

Comment: @Josh K: You may want to try using MacPorts or a different package manager instead to get a working copy.

Comment: @Chealion: I try to stay away from those as much as possible, but it looks like it only has 0.5.1 available as a package anyways.

Comment: MacPorts currently has FFmpeg 0.6 available.

Comment: @Josh K: Fair enough. Most of the less expensive "converters" are just GUIs to FFMPEG and related utilities.

Comment: @sentinel: I'll double check, I my search returned 5.1...

Comment: Accepting because it's the correct answer and at the core of 90% of the encoding programs.

Comment: I did a MacPorts update (took a half and hour) found ffmpeg 0.6 and installed it (took a few hours). Overall this works, thanks!

Comment: @JoshK - for many setups macports now does binary downloads so this should only take minutes now

Answer (score 3):

A couple free programs:

- [Miro Video Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/) - Free but very limited in terms of customization. But does support Theora and VP8l
- [FFMPEG on the command line](http://www.ffmpeg.org) - Harder to use but it's free.
- [Video Monkey](http://videomonkey.org/Video_Monkey/About.html) - Based on the open sourced replacement of Visual Hub